# TextView would not horizontally center

Tags: android, layout

My layout is the following:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display_city"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/pollenType"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/get_pollen_index"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
    android:textSize="40sp" />
```

As you can tell, `Philadelphia, PA` is left-aligned. No matter what I change, whether it's centering horizontal and vertical to true, it stays left-aligned.

I have tried changing the layout via the XML and graphical user interface. In the graphical user interface, it indeed is "centered", but it remains non-centered. My layout positions are consistent across all my textviews, so I am unsure as to why this particular TextView is not centered.

[image]

Comment: use `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: Ah that fixed it.. Should I use gravity center for all my other TextViews? It is weird that this is the only TextView that doesn't align..

Comment: post all your xml layout

Comment: @theGreenCabbage : the TextView is centered on your screen using the attributes ( centerInParent , centerHorizontal , or centerVertical ) . But , in order to center the text inside your TextView, you should use gravity attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options...

**One:** Give the TextView `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

**Two:** Keep the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and use `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

`layout_gravity` defines gravity of the view within its parent. Your textView already takes the full width because of `match_parent`, so centering it horizontally inside its parent does nothing.

`gravity`, on the other hand, defines the gravity of its *contents*.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling the `display_city` TextView to be as wide as the screen.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

However, its text is left aligned by default. That's why it looks this way.

You have two alternatives for what you want:

1. Keep the width as `match_parent` and center the text inside the TextView (with `gravity`).
2. Set the width to `wrap_content` and center the View inside its parent (with `layout_gravity`).

Answer (score 0):

You can center the text using the gravity xml attributes :

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your width equals `match_parent` and therefore the edges of your `TextView` already touch the edges of the parent view. You should rather center the text in the `TextView` with `android:gravity="center"`.